# Full control user can't create service applications

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, farm-admin

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and have a user that is a farm administration and full control for the site collection.

For some reason I can't create a new service applications.

When I go the Manage Service Application page the "New" button is visible but disabled and I can't press it.

It happens in many places in the central administration pages.

How can I resolve that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Start internet explorer as administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour If you are Farm administrator but your account is not in local admin on the server.

By default, Farm administrator don't have full control on the Central Admin i.e as Farm Admin you can't create the web application can't change the service account etc. The reason is, some activity required local admin rights on server i.e when you create a service application, it create the site and application pool in the IIS which you can't do without local admin account.

If you want to get it done by your ID then add yourself into local admin on the server. Otherwise, you can login with farm admin account.

[SharePoint 2016 Farm Admin account Vs Farm Administrator Group in Central Admin.](http://krossfarm.com/?p=214)